# The center of the dihedral group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

How to prove that the center of the dihedral group $D_{2n}$ is $\{1,r^{n}\}$ and the center of $D_{2n-1}$ is $\{1\}$?

I don't know how to prove it in this general case.

Comment: Does [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1469131/center-of-dihedral-group) help ?

Comment: It's really awkward to structure the title so that "$D_{2n} = \{1, r^n\}"$ is a phrase. I understand you're saying the center, and not the whole group, is what the equality refers to, but it just *looks* so wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us conjugate a general element of the form $r^as$ by another element $r^bs$.
$$(r^bs)r^as(sr^{-b})=r^bsr^ar^{-b}=r^{2b-a}s$$
Since in general this depends on $b$, an element of this form cannot be in the center. Now let's conjugate $r^a$ by $r^bs$:
$$(r^bs)r^a(sr^{-b})=r^{-a}$$
For completeness we note
$$r^br^ar^{-b}=r^a$$
Thus the only way an element $r^a$ can be in the center is if $r^a=r^{-a}$, meaning the rotation commutes with reflections. This means
$$r^{2a}=1$$
$a=0$ will always work; for a dihedral group of order $2(2n)$, we can also take $a=n$. For a dihedral group of order $2(2n-1)$ there is no $a$ such that $r^a$ has order $2$, hence the center is trivial.