# Identifying the center of the dihedral group of order $2n$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, dihedral-groups

> If $$D_{2n} = \{r^i s^j, \quad 0 ≤ i ≤ n − 1, \quad 0 ≤ j ≤ 1 \}$$ is the dihedral group of order $2n$, show that the center of $D_{2n}$, $n > 2$ is the trivial subgroup if $n$ is odd, and is the subgroup $\{e, r^{n/2} \}$ if $n$ is even.

I don't know how to proceed with this one.

Kindly help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know the multiplication law in $D_{2n}$?

Comment: @Mosher No, I haven't studied that yet.

Comment: @Robin You can't define a group without knowing its group law.

Comment: I am going to vote to reopen, because the duplicate was posted in 2019, and this one dates from 2017.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for commenting. Surely the fact that this one has an answer trumps the "age" bit? Anyway, I was doing some (superficial) digging as I was sure I had seen this question a few times before. I only found 3 (maybe 4), which are the two here [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1608582/10513), which is the oldest of the 3 but is closed for being just a problem statement.

Comment: (The "maybe 4" is because of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1469131/10513), which is morally the same question.)

Comment: @user1729 Yes I see the argument! I would have preferred to have just voted to reopen, but because of my high reputation count it reopened immediately.

Comment: @DerekHolt If the duplicate has answers already, maybe let us keep that one?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Yes that is OK with me! I won't vote any more myself.