# Nonabelian dihedral groups and a question in number theory

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, dihedral-groups

I'll use a concrete definition of a dihedral group $D_{2n}$ which emphasizes its group structure:

> $D_{2n}$ consists of distinct elements $r_0,...,r_{n-1},s_0,...,s_{n-1}$ so that for any $i \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $r_{i + n} = r_i, s_{i + n} s_i$ and for any $i,j \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $r_ir_j = r_{i + j}, r_is_j = s_{i + j}, s_ir_j = s_{i - j}, s_is_j = r_{i - j}$.

It's easy to see that all $r_i's$ commute in $D_{2n}$, hence the only elements for which it is possible not to commute are $s_i$ and $s_j$ or $r_i$ and $s_j$.

$s_is_j = s_js_i$ whenever $i - j \equiv j - i \bmod n$ and $r_is_j = s_jr_i$ whenever $i + j \equiv i - j \bmod n$, hence $D_{2n}$ is noncommutative if and only if either

- there is $0 \leq j < n$ so that $n\nmid 2j$, or
- there are $0 \leq i,j < n$  so that $n\nmid 2(i - j)$.

Using this result, it's not hard to establish that $D_2$ and $D_4$ are abelian.

I wonder how we can use this to prove that $D_{2n}$ is not abelian for $n \geq 3$. I'm not interested in a possible geometric proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you can prove that
$$r_1s_1\neq s_1r_1$$
It follows easily from your definition.

Answer (score 0):

By definition there is a rotation $r$ in $D_n$, $n\ge 3$ and a reflection $s$ such that 
$$
srs^{-1}=r^{-1}\neq r.
$$ 
So $D_n$ is non-abelian. We can also give a second proof by determining the *center* of $D_n$. A group is abelian iff it equals its center. However, we easily see that $Z(D_n)$ is much smaller than that:

[The center of the dihedral group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1608582/the-center-of-the-dihedral-group)