# Prove $D_{24}$ is not isomorphic to $S_4$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

The question from *"Abstract Algebra,"* by Dummit & Foote is:

> Prove that the dihedral group $D_{24}$ is not isomorphic to $S_4$.

We can express the presentation of

$$D_{24}=\{r,s | r^{12}=s^2=1, rs=sr^{-1}\}.$$

Obviously for some permutation $\sigma \in S_4, \sigma ^4=1$ and $(1 2)(1 2)=1$. So $S_4$ can also be expressed as $$S_4=\{ \sigma, k | \sigma^4=k^2=1\},$$ where $k=(1 2)$ so $D_{24}$ is homomorphic to $S_4$.

Also, $|D_{24}|=24$ and $S_4=4!$ so $D_{24} \cong S_4$. This is contradicting the question.

Why am I wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What homomorphism $D_{24} \to S_4$ are you considering, exactly? Also, finding a homomorphism between two groups with the same cardinality is not sufficient for it to be an isomorphism... (Consider the trivial homomorphism between any two groups of the same order.)

Comment: @Alex Provost I'm not sure, but I assume its similar to the homomorphism $D_{2n} \to D_{2k}$ for $k|n$ which was an example in the bookI got this question from

Comment: Your presentation of $S_4$ is incorrect. The group you wrote down is $\Bbb Z/4 * \Bbb Z/2$ which is certainly infinite.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To show that two groups are isomorphic, it is not sufficient to find a homomorphism between them, even if they have the same order. For instance, you can always pick the trivial homomorphism, which is never an isomorphism (unless both groups are trivial). For a homomorphism to be an isomorphism, it has to be injective and surjective. If you know beforehand that the two finite groups have the same order, then injectivity is equivalent to surjectivity, so you only have to check one.

That being said, I think you had the following idea: define a homomorphism $\phi:D_{24} \to S_4$ by declaring that $\phi(r) = \sigma$ and $\phi(s) = k$ and extending this to the whole group. To be precise, I will use the generators $\sigma = (1234), k=(12)$ for $S_4$. At a first glance, it seems fine because order considerations show that the relations $r^{12} =1$ and $s^{2} = 1$ are preserved. However, this $\phi$ is not well-defined because the third relation $(rs)^2 = 1$ in $D_{24}$ is not preserved. In other words, if $\phi$ were to be a homomorphism, we should have $1 = \phi(1) = \phi((rs)^2) = (\sigma k)^2$. However, $(\sigma k)^2 = (143)$ is not the identity element in $S_4$. The moral of this story is: if you want to define a homomorphism on the generators of a group defined via a presentation, you have to make sure that all the relations are preserved by your would-be homomorphism.

Answer (score 13):

$D_{24}$ and $S_4$ are not isomorphic because
$D_{24}$ has an element of order $12$ but $S_4$ doesn't.

Comment: why not though? Isn't $\sigma^{12}=1$?

Comment: @WilliamKin, $\sigma^{12}=1$ does not imply $\sigma$ has order $12$. In fact, $\sigma$ has order $4$.

Answer (score 5):

$D_{24}$ and $S_4$ are not isomorphic,  because $S_4$ has trivial center, but $D_{24}$ does not - see this question: [Center of dihedral group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1469131/center-of-dihedral-group)

Two finite groups (of the same order) being "homomorphic" does not mean they are "isomorphic".